# Regex Python filtering a list of concatenated strings

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling with a regular expression. It is supposed to match only those strings that are a list of 3 words separated by `|`.

A word may contain any character (no newline etc., of course) but `|`

Examples:

```
word01|wörd|wä4rd # only this should be matched
word04|würd|wä4rd|of
word02|wörd|wä4rd|off|j
word01|wörd
```

I'd like to match those that have exactly 2 `|`. A simple count function could do it, but that is not available in my case. So I need a regular expression.

This obviously does not do the trick:

`^[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|+[^\|]$`

What's the correct regular expression? What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
^([^|]+\|){2}[^|]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

You have misplaced the last `+` sign, instead of:

```
^[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|+[^\|]$
```

use

```
^[^\|]+\|[^\|]+\|[^\|]+$
//               ^____^
```

Comment: `[^\|]` matches any character except pipe and backslash, there is no escaping needed for the pipe in that case.

Comment: @sphere: I agree that `|` doesn't need to be escaped, but `[\|]` doesn't match `\ ` or `|`, it should be `[\\|]` to match `\ `.

Comment: I agree. Interesting that it seems to have no difference if `[^\|]` or `[^|]` is used.

Comment: Yes, I misplaced that. What a foolish mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Correct would be: `'^[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+$'`